# Python openpyxl changing fill color of a specific marker on the scatter graph

Tags: python, openpyxl

I was trying to make a scatter graph appear in excel (`.xlsx` file), and plot markers on it, before filling the markers individually with different colors, to no avail. The following code shows what I have tried in Python, using the `openpyxl` library. Thank you anyone for your help!

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.chart import (
    ScatterChart,
    Reference,
    Series,
)
from openpyxl.chart.marker import Marker, DataPoint

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

rows = [
    ("Sample", ),
    (1, 10),
    (2, 11),
    (3, 12),
    (4, 13),
    (5, 14),
    (5, 15),
    (6, 16),
    (7, 17),
]

for r in rows:
    ws.append(r)

c = ScatterChart()
xvalues = Reference(ws, min_col=1, min_row=2, max_row=9)
yvalues = Reference(ws, min_col=2, min_row=2, max_row=9)
series = Series(xvalues, yvalues)

series.marker = Marker('circle', size=10)
series.graphicalProperties.line.noFill = True

pt = DataPoint(idx=5)
pt.graphicalProperties.solidFill = "800000"
series.dPt.append(pt)

c.series.append(series)
ws.add_chart(c, "C1")

wb.save("marker_fill.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate several random color and assign them to the points of your chart.

```py
from random import randint
```

```py
for i in range(1, len(rows) - 1):
    pt = DataPoint(idx=i)
    pt.graphicalProperties.solidFill = "%06x" % randint(0, 0xFFFFFF) #random color
    series.dPt.append(pt)
```

Comment: The issue is not with the random color generation, but rather not being able to directly update the fill color of a marker on the  scatter graph. I have tried using this code, but it doesn't works too.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't really understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

I have not found a way to update the fill color of a particular marker on the scatter graph. However, I have found a workaround to fill the color of the marker individually while plotting it. Essentially, instead of using the `max_row` arg for the `Reference` method to define the last row to read, I would iterate through each row in the data and plot it one by one, while updating the `spPr=GraphicalProperties(solidFill=)` arg in the `Marker` method.

This effectively gives the same results as before.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.chart import (
    ScatterChart,
    Reference,
    Series,
)
from openpyxl.chart.shapes import GraphicalProperties
from openpyxl.chart.marker import Marker, DataPoint

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

rows = [
    ("Sample", ),
    (1, 10),
    (2, 11),
    (3, 12),
    (4, 13),
    (5, 14),
    (5, 15),
    (6, 16),
    (7, 17),
]

marker_colors = [
    "800000",
    "0000FF",
    "800000",
    "0000FF",
    "FF7F7F",
    "800000",
    "800000",
    "FF7F7F",
]

for r in rows:
    ws.append(r)

c = ScatterChart()

for i in range(1, 9):
    xvalues = Reference(ws, min_col=1, min_row=i)
    yvalues = Reference(ws, min_col=2, min_row=i)

    series = Series(xvalues, yvalues)
    series.marker = Marker(
        'circle',
        size=15,
        spPr=GraphicalProperties(solidFill=marker_colors[i - 1]))
    series.graphicalProperties.line.noFill = True

    c.series.append(series)

ws.add_chart(c, "C1")
wb.save("marker_fill.xlsx")
```